# Error bars in scatter plot without line joining the points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show error in x using error bars, but I want the error bars on individual points in the scatter plot. But when I run this code (given below) I get this plot [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAEoV.png). I only want the scatter points with error in x. How do I remove the lines joining the points? Thanks for your help!

```
pyplot.scatter(mat0[:,1], mat0[:,3], label = "herbig stars", color=colors[0]);
pyplot.scatter(mat1mod1, mat1mod5, label = "COUP data of SpT F5-M6 ", color=colors[1]);
pyplot.scatter(mat1mod1, mat1mod6, label = "COUP data of SpT B0-F5", color=colors[2]);
pyplot.errorbar(mat0[:,1], mat0[:,3], xerr=0.1,)
pyplot.errorbar(mat1mod1, mat1mod5, xerr=0.1, )
pyplot.errorbar(mat1mod1, mat1mod6, xerr=0.1,)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some fake data so that this is a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for your help!